# How to update the future in FutureBuilder to get new data while using GetX

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder, flutter-getx

I am using GetX and FutureBuilder to build a list of Cards from my DB.
Lets say I have 10 products in DB then 10 cards are shown. When I add one more product, the Cards on the HomeScreen aren't updated and I have to Navigate in and Out of page to show the 11th product.

How can I force the update i.e. probably make a "Refresh" button that may load the latest data.

**PS: I do not want to use STREAM-BUILDER as I don't wish to listen to all changes actively but only when needed. I also cannot use SetState() as I am using GetX hence no StatefulWidget.**

Here is my Card class:

```
FutureBuilder(
                future: databaseController.getData()
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                   return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                          GetX<FindDeviceLocation>(builder: (controller) {
                        return CreateTheCard(
                            lindex: index,
                            location: snapshot.data[index]["location"],
                            summary: snapshot.data[index]["summary"],
                            description: snapshot.data[index]["description"],
                            category: snapshot.data[index]["category"],
                            imageURL: snapshot.data[index]["adImage"],
                            
                            onTapFunction: () => Get.to(DetailPage(
                                  post: snapshot.data[index],
                                )));
                      }),
```

This is my method that fetches data from DB:

```
Future getData() async {
    QuerySnapshot _firebaseDb = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("items")
        .where("status", isEqualTo: true)
        .orderBy("postTime", descending: true)
        .get();
          
    return _firebaseDb.docs;
  }
```

Comment: create a bool obs variable.`var gettingDataCompleted = false.obs` and inside builder check it for rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Use the getx worker
Ever:
If data change you can update the view

```
ever(index, (value) {
// call your function here
// any code will be called any time index changes
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `databaseController` has a method call `update()`,so you can call `databaseController.update()` when you need to update your data.